Can Asynchronous Riverpod Notifier Methods get into a race with each other?
Let's say you have implemented a riverpod notifier class which holds a list of instances of a class in its state. That notifier class then also has a variety of different notifier methods which update the state by removing / adding list elements in multiple different ways. Some of them are asynchronous.
Let's say that your app then calls these notifier methods in a variety of different contexts / widgets, depending on whatever task executed in your app. That makes it possible that one of these asynchronous notifier methods may be called while another one is still running.
What I'm afraid of is that if two methods are called at nearly the same time (e.g., from different contexts in the app), and these methods both read from the state and then modify it: Could they overwrite each other's changes?
Or does riverpod implement some kind of FIFO-logic for this, to assure that notifier methods of the same notifier are always executed one after the other?
If riverpod does not assure this, I'd have to implement some kind of logic which "queues" all notifier calls via a (thus only) public method of the notifier, and then performs these state updates one-by-one internally by using a Queue and respective private notifier methods, both of these scoped to an internal use of the notifier only. To assure that there won't be any of the above-mentioned race-conditions.
But I wondered if that is not already provided anyways, by the package?

if those two methods are not async methods (like TodosNotifier.addTodo or TodosNotifier.removeTodo or TodosNotifier.toggle shown in https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider) it is impossible that two of them could be run at the same time

As my title says, my question particularly concerns async notifier calls. I guess it wouldn't make sense to allow simultaneous notifier method executions by design, but wanted to double-check.

"I guess it wouldn't make sense to allow simultaneous notifier method executions by design" - if your method is async there are no means in riverpod to prevent this: you can call any number of such methods provided there is at least one Future awaited in your code

Why are you holding a list of states instead of simply using a family to manage the collection of providers with individual lifecycles?

@pskink I meant if you consider that notifier methods are supposed to read from the current state and update the state according to performed changes; wouldn't it make sense in that way to add FIFO behaviour to that, or have it out of the box? was merely a thought. Using a Queue into which you add objects to be processed (each representing a notifier to be called), in that way you could reach that behaviour. Just wondered if this is necessary with riverpod, and apparently it is...?

@RandalSchwartz are you referring to this? I didn't know about this, but it seems that its docs are outdated, so not sure if this is still recommended? But the examples shown, isn't that the same principle as passing args? In that case it's not an option, as the notifiers are in my case keepAlive:true notifiers. Or am I misunderstanding you? I don' understand how families shall be the solution of the problem of my question?

Like as far as I can tell, if I have the same notifier methods being called on the same family, you're back to the exact same problem I'm asking about, so I don't get how this should help?

I guess you’re talking about handling concurrency in Riverpod. Unlike Flutter BLoC, which is event-based and processes events one at a time, Riverpod doesn’t handle concurrency for you.
If you call two async notifier methods at the same time, there’s a chance they could overwrite each other’s changes, which is something to watch out for.
To deal with this in Riverpod, you’d need to handle it manually using something like a Mutex or a custom queue to ensure updates happen one at a time.
There was actually an issue raised in the Riverpod GitHub where it was clarified that concurrency needs to be managed manually,

Thanks, was the info I was looking for. The repo owner himself there suggests to refactor the async notifier methods to get rid of the problem, so this indeed seems to be necssary. Thanks again!
